# SimpleXML: Getting attributes into variables

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am building my website with a central XML-file and SimpleXML. The pages have some different features like the language. I would like to put these features into the XML-file with attributes of the parent node:

```
<content>
  <item id="one" lang="en">
    <title>Hello</title>
  </item>
</content>
```

I call a certain item by the id-attribute and I know how to call subnodes like :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$lang = $bl->xpath('/content/item[@id="one"]/title/text()'); 
   $lang = $lang[0]; echo $lang;
```

But how do I get the attribute LANG of an item with the id="one" into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

the path to the attribute
`/content/item[@id="one"]/@lang`
the value of the attribute `data(/content/item[@id="one"]/@lang)`

Comment: Thanks alot, Chrisis. I tried this before, but it didn't work, because I closed the path with 'text()'. This is the dump:

'SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => one
                            [lang] => en
                        )

                    [title] => TITLE ...'